# Unable to figure out equation involving imaginary numbers

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I have been trying this for a while, but cannot get how to finally solve it. This is what we have:

> If $x$ and $y$ are real, solve the equation: $(xi) / (1 + iy) = (3x + 4i) / (x + 3y)$ where $i^2 = -1$

I ended up with: $x^2i - 3x - 4i + 4y$. However, I have no idea how to continue, as I always worked with equations in the form $a + bi$, but in this particular case, how should I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure $j$? this is $i$, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo (depending of the book, "i" or "j" is used). Edited to fix it, thanks.

Comment: $x^2i-3x-4i-4y$ should be $x^2i-3x-4i+4y$, right ?

Comment: Yes, because you put it on the left side and then multiply it by $i^2 (which is -1). Edited and sorry for these silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with
$$
(x^2-4)i+(4y-3x)=0,
$$
so that $x^2=4$ and $y=3x/4$, i.e., $(x,y)=(2,3/2)$ and $(x,y)=(-2,-3/2)$.

Comment: I see I just missed taking the _i_ out to multiply it by the part of the equation which had _i_ - ending up with a couple equations that easily gives you the values. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{xi}{1+iy}=\frac{3x+4i}{x+3y}\iff xi(x+3y)=(1+iy)(3x+4i)$$
so we develop and cancel we find
$$4y-3x+(x^2-4)i=0\iff (4y-3x=0)\land (x^2-4=0)\\\iff (x=\pm2)\land(y=\frac 3 4 x=\pm\frac 32)$$
so the answer is
$$(x,y)\in\left\{\left(2,\frac 3 2\right);\left(-2,-\frac 3 2\right)\right\}$$

Comment: That's what I have, too. So there is a sign mistake in the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Assuming $j$ is a typo of $i,$

qe have $$i\cdot x(x+3y)=(3x+4i)(1+iy)=3x-4y+i(4+3xy)$$

Comparing the real & the imaginary parts $$3x-4y=0\ \ \ \ (1)\text{ and } x(x+3y)=4+3xy\iff x^2=4\  \ \  \ (2)$$

So, we have two equation with two unknown variables